# Routing in Dotnetnuke CMS in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, dotnetnuke

I have a Dotnetnuke CMS, wherein i want to implement routing. i am using asp.net 4.0

I have successfully implemented the Routing on Plain ASP.Net WebForms, but cannot see a way to implement the same on Dotnetnuke, as Dotnetnuke has Virtual .aspx pages, and Routing requires the Physical location of the file.

I am using below code for Routing on ASP.Net Webforms.

```
  Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("ArticlePage", "sample/{articleid}", "~/article.aspx")
    End Sub
```

But same does not works on Dotnetnuke. Can anyone help me with the same.

Answer (score 1):

In DNN 7+ you can use the IServiceRouteMapper, something along the lines of the following code

```
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;

namespace Christoc.Modules.dnnsimplearticle.services
{
    public class DnnSimpleArticleRouteMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
    {

        public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
        {
            mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("DnnSimpleArticle","Default", "{controller}.ashx/{action}",
                                     new[] { "Christoc.Modules.dnnsimplearticle.services" });

            //mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("MyServices", "default", "{controller}/{action}", new {"MyServices"});
        }
    }
```

Pulled from https://dnnsimplearticle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#cs/services/DnnSimpleArticleRouteMapper.cs